# Python pyats and rich module

Tags: python, rich

I'm trying to print the output from a pyats to the rich module. Here is the output

```
{
  "cdp": {
    "index": {
      "1": {
        "capability": "R S I",
        "device_id": "SW22.lab.com",
        "hold_time": 150,
        "local_interface": "Ethernet0/0",
        "platform": "",
        "port_id": "LinuxUniEth0/0"
      },
      "2": {
        "capability": "R S I",
        "device_id": "SW23.lab.com",
        "hold_time": 147,
        "local_interface": "Ethernet0/0",
        "platform": "",
        "port_id": "LinuxUniEth0/0"
      },
```

And when I need to print from capability to local_interface. With this lines

```
for k, v in preoutput['cdp'].items():

    deid = v.get('device_id')
    loint = v.get('local_interface')
    holdt = v.get('hold_time')
    portid = v.get('port_id')

table.add_row(k, deid)
```

I only get print out the Index word.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Rich question, but your code is only looking at the dictionary with key "index".

Perhaps this is what you wanted?

```
for k, v in preoutput['cdp']["index"].items():
```

Comment: thanks but still not showing, I think I'm missing some code. thanks.